# can any one help me to understand this message in cmd when run ng serve (Angular 8)?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli

when i run `ng serve` this is the output and i am not able to understand its meaning. Can anyone tell if its an error?

```
i ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://localhost:4200/webpack-dev-server/
i ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from /
i ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to //index.html
```

Comment: There is no error. It's just information messages.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This isn't an error, it simply says if the (lite) server encounters a undefined route it will be redirected to the `index.html` page.

Comment: This answer saved so much of my time. He is right, try to comment all routes except the one which you will be testing is falling. That one bad route is causing this issue.

Comment: Very useful answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to update new version angular, and 
*this* is my solution

```
#ng update @angular/cli @angular/core#
```