# Weird text in Visual Studio output window when running Angular SPA with MVC backend

Tags: angular, visual-studio, webpack, single-page-application

I've got this minor problem where the following shows up in VS's output window when I run the app:

```
i ∩╜ówds∩╜ú: Project is running at http://localhost:55217/webpack-dev-server/

Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices:Information: i ∩╜ówds∩╜ú: webpack output is served from /
i ∩╜ówds∩╜ú: 404s will fallback to //index.html

...

Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices:Information: ** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:55217, open your browser on http://localhost:55217/ **
i ∩╜ówdm∩╜ú: Compiled successfully.
```

I suspect this is some *UTF-8* issue.  The application runs ok.  I'm just hoping someone recognizes the surrounding text, and can maybe help me hone in on what this text really is, and maybe a suggestion on how to fix it.

P.S. - Open to suggestions for a better title to this issue.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56954866/can-any-one-help-me-to-understand-this-message-in-cmd-when-run-ng-serve-angular), the surrounding Text should be i [wds], and that's not error message,just info.

Comment: Thanks, at least I have a clue what's happening now.
 i ∩╜ówds∩╜ú <==> i ｢wds｣ 
Or for some reason, ｢ is being displayed as ∩╜ó and ｣ as ∩╜ú
(I copied the original text into this comment, and it changed)